# How to work with BarEditItem and BarCheckItem in RibbonControl Winforms Devexpress ?

Tags: winforms, checkbox, devexpress, ribbon-control

I need CheckBox in RibbonControl and if it checked I need to perform some task if not checked I need to perform some other task. So I tried `barCheckItem1` It is working properly what I expect but it is Displaying like Button I need exact CheckBox. So again I used `barEditItem1` in this Item "CheckChanged" event is not available then if i write code in "EditValueChanged" event, if I check or Uncheck the event not fired. How to complete my task ? 
I need CheckBox with CheckedChanged Event.

Comment: The Devexpress support web site has all this information you should check there. Look at the BarManager add->Editors->CheckedComboBoxEdit You need to access the RepositorItem for the CheckedComboBoxEdit to interact with the Checked Combo Box.I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to access the control itself:

One way is:

```
CheckEdit checkEdit = barEditItem.Edit as CheckEdit;
bool isChecked = checkEdit.Checked;
```

The other is the repository editor directly:

```
 bool isChecked = repositoryItemCheckedEdit.ValueChecked;
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

Add a `BarEditItem` with `CheckEdit`, attach event `CheckedChanged` of `RepositoryItemCheckEdit`. You're done.

```
private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((CheckEdit) sender).Checked);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool? ischecked = (bool?)barEditItem1.EditValue;
     if(!ischecked.HasValue)
     {
       //In determinate state
     }
     else
     {
       if(ischecked.Value)
       {
           //Checked
       }
       else
       {
           //Not Checked
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sriram already I tried this repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged Event but how to get if it is checked or not ?? I need to perform like this ` if (barCheckItem1.Checked)
            { //code } else { //code }`

Comment: the barCheckedItem is just a place holder the repositoryItemCheckedEdit1 is the control isself soyou need to access that control not the place holder.